# How to update the UI when using a BackgroundDownloader with parallel downloads?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp

In a WinRT. I have a download in background method and the download progress should be updated in the UI portion.

The code I have is

```
             public async static Task DownloadSingleFile(string name, SoundClass sc)
             {
                    var dl = new BackgroundDownloader();
                    dl.CostPolicy = BackgroundTransferCostPolicy.Always;
                    file = await localSoundsFolder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                    var d = dl.CreateDownload(new Uri(uriToDownloadFrom), file);
                    d.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.Default;

                    var progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
                    try
                    {
                        await d.StartAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progressCallback);
                        CancellationTokenSource token = Utility.cancellationList[sc];
                        if (token != null)
                        {
                            token.Cancel();
                            Utility.cancellationList.Remove(sc);
                            Debug.WriteLine("The sc has been removed from the download list");
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return;
                    }
              }
```

And the download method looks like this

```
        private static void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation download)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Callback");
            var value = download.Progress.BytesReceived * 100 / download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive;
            Debug.WriteLine("The bytesReceived is {0} and total bytes is {1}", download.Progress.BytesReceived.ToString(), download.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(10);
            //Update the UI here
            if (download.Progress.Status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed || value >= 100)
            {
               //Perform opertaion
            }
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is since I have multiple download operations happening I cannot directly perform the operation to update the UI. I was wondering how can I can send a parameter `DownloadProgress` method which is bound to the UI and helps in the update operation .

Comment: Can you please show or share some resources which is helpful for the implementation of multiple file download with real time progress and cancellation option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use lambdas for this:

```
int downloadId = ...;
var progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(x => DownloadProgress(x, downloadId));
```

Then your progress updater can use it:

```
private static void DownloadProgress(DownloadOperation download, int downloadId)
{
  ... // use downloadId
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!